# Stochastic Integrals over infinite time horizon

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

The stochastic Integral w.r.t Semimartingales is defined for predictable Processes $\phi$ where $\int_{0}^T \phi_t dt < \infty$. How would I extend the Definition, when I want to integrate over $[0,\infty)$.
I am trying to solve a optimal consumption Problem over a infinite time horizon. In https://openaccess.nhh.no/nhh-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/163833/framstad%20nils%20christian%200599.pdf?sequence=1 on Page 5 the admissible Controls are just required to be predictable.

Comment: You can assume $\int_0^T\phi_t\,dt<\infty$ for all $T\,.$ It seems strange to consider integrals w.r.t. Semimartingales that are defined at $T=\infty\,.$ First of all, a Brownian motion is not defined there and that is trivially a stochastic integral w.r.t. a semi martingale. Secondly, for practical purposes an  arbitrarily large time horizon should be good enough. Which economy requires an infinite time horizon?

Comment: @KurtG. It isn't that the economy requires infinite time horizon, it's that the infinite horizon problem is often easier to solve.  In practice, the solution to the infinite horizon problem is (hopefully) a good approximation for a large but finite time horizon problem.

Comment: I guess there is a wording problem: as I explained the time horizon $[0,\infty\color{red}{]}$ is non sensical even for a standard Brownian motion. To define your integrals on $[0,\infty\color{red}{)}$ the integrability condition I mentioned is trivially sufficient.

Comment: @KurtG. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  One doesn't need to define a function at $\infty$ for its infinite integral to be defined.  Of course there would need to be conditions to ensure the integral is well-defined, but I don't see why it would immediately be nonsensical.

Comment: In OP you wrote that you want to integrate over $[0,\infty]\,.$ This made me think you want to define stochastic integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty X_s\,dY_s\,.$ They are non sensical since for $X_s\equiv 1$ and $Y_s$ being a Brownian motion $Y_\infty$ does not exist. The wording "infinite time horizon" means what? $[0,\infty]$ or $[0,\infty)$ ? I would opt for the latter. An even better definition of that would be stochastic integrals $\int_0^TX_s\,dY_s$ for arbitrarily large but finite $T\,.$

Comment: I made a typo, I meant of course $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @KurtG. Why does finding an example where $\int_0^\infty X_s dY_s$ isn't well-defined mean that it is _never_ well-defined?  If you have an integrability condition like $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty X_s^2 d\langle Y,Y \rangle_s] < \infty$ (or $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^T X_s^2 d\langle Y,Y \rangle_s] < C$ for some constant $C$ and all $T \in [0,\infty)$), then $\int_0^\infty X_s dY_s$ is well-defied.

Comment: I did not say it is never well-defined. But even the most prototypical example I gave does not satisfy your very demanding integrability condition here.

Comment: @KurtG. You said it's non sensical, which seems like an even stronger statement than "never well-defined."  Your "prototypical example" is like saying that $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$ is non sensical because it isn't finite for $f(t) \equiv 1$.  Demanding or not, the fact that there _is_ an integrability condition means that these integrals are far from non sensical.